# "view_thread" event of Gmail.js of Kartik Talwar not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, gmail

I am working on chrome extension. In which I am currently using the following event:

```
gmail.observe.on('view_thread', function(obj) {
  console.log('conversation thread opened', obj); // gmail.dom.thread object
});
```

Previously it is working fine. But due to some reasons recently it stopped working (might be some UI changes made by Gmail)

Here is the reference for gmail.js that I am using: https://github.com/KartikTalwar/gmail.js

Please help me how to correct this.

Comment: The library is complex so it's best to ask its author on github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the bug of the same by doing the following change in the Gmail.js

```
"view_thread": {
            class: ["Bu", "nH"], // class depends if is_preview_pane - Bu for preview pane, nH for standard view
            sub_selector: "div.if",
            handler: function (match, callback) {
                match = new api.dom.thread(match);
                callback(match);

                // look for any email elements in this thread that are currently displaying
                // and fire off any view_email sub_observers for each of them
                setTimeout(function () {
                    var email = match.dom("opened_email");
                    if (email.length) {
                        api.observe.trigger_dom("view_email", email, api.tracker.dom_observers.view_thread.sub_observers.view_email.handler);
                    }
                }, 500)
            },
```

As you can see that I added setTimeout method and calling "view_email" method after 500 ms. Here the actual problem is Gmail UI responds late and view_email event is called before Gmail UI renders that's why event not called.